# Phonological ambiguity that changes the syntactic structure

Tags: syntax, phonology, ambiguity

I'm looking for two sentences that have phonological/phonetic ambiguity (like John's feat, and John's feet), but with different syntactic structures.
For example, "John's feat was a big deal" and "John's feet was a big deal" doesn't qualify for what I'm looking for because even though they have phonological ambiguity, their syntactic structure is the same.

I can't come up with any...any help would be appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Fruit flies like a banana* is a famous example.

Comment: That's ambiguous in writing, but not necessarily in phonology. The stress pattern will probably differ noticeably (and sufficient to disambiguate) according to whether or not *fruit flies* is a compound.

Answer (score 3):

This kind of phonological ambiguity is
frequent enough, also because sound may be distorted. Actually, it has
been considered important enough in speech processing that a specific
representational device was created for it. It is the so called "**word
lattice**" used to represent in a compressed way the various sequences
of words that could correspond to the phonological sequence, each word
corresponding to a subpart of that sequence. Note that the different
sequences of word may imply different way of cutting of the string into parts
corresponding to words as for example ([taken from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holorime)) "a
cruise, eh, lass?" and "accrues, hélas!".

Some parsing techniques can directly accomodate word lattices, as they
would a word sequence, and either eliminate some variants of the
phonological ambiguity because they cannot be made syntactically
correct, or treat them as a syntactic ambiguity problem, using
whatever means at their disposal for this purpose.

Exercise in phonological ambiguity have been pushed to an extreme with
holorime verses. A well known one in French is

> Gall, amant de la Reine, alla, tour magnanime!
>      Galamment de l'Arène à la Tour Magne, à Nîmes.

You can fin several more at http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vers_holorimes.

Answer (score 1):

Phonological ambiguity is often the result of phonological change. *Feet* and *feat* are homonyms in Modern English, but they were pronounced differently in Middle English. The Great Vowel Shift merged both ME long /æ:/ and long /e:/ into Modern English tense /i/, whence /fit/.

So another example of phonological change that changes the syntactic structure -- in fact a recurring prototypical example -- is the [Grammaticalization Cycle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Grammaticalization.pdf). This happened in Latin around 0 CE, leading to the Romance languages; and in English a millennium later, after the Norman invasion make English a language spoken by illiterate peasants.

Comment: "John has lead soldiers."

Answer (score 0):

Buhari lost his " site" or " sight. 
   this is an ambiguous statement, because it may be buhar lost site ,means the piece of land 
or buhsri loose his eyes.

Comment: structure will be the same here too.

Answer (score -1):

> passenger:  How long will the bus stay at the station?
>
> Conductor: from two to two to two two

Is this is an example of phonological ambiguity?

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is an example that fits what the question is looking for?

Comment: @curiousdannii This can alternatively parse as "from two two to two to two" assuming the bus can stop for nearly a full day (or ignoring meaning of time specifications), which is a semantic issue, hence irrelevant here. So there is a phonological ambiguity with different syntactic structures. ---> susan: No upvote though, since you should be giving the answer, not asking a further question (but I did not downvote: you did provide an answer, even though you did not seem to see it).